# Why is my footer doesn't go under all of the content / divs?

Tags: css

I'm almost finished coding my website. I made my footer under *all* divs, and sections. I used a new section, `<footer>`.

But the footer doesn't go under the contents. why? It is stickied to top.

> http://generationx-pk.net/tools/index.html

How do I make it stick to the bottom, but not always, you know when you go on the website, you will not see the footer until you scroll down.

Comment: Does [this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) suit your needs?

Comment: your header has a height set to 55px.  Remove this and your problem is solved.

Comment: also IDs should be unique, use a class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your `css` to remove height property,

```
.header {
height: 55px; 
}
```

change to `height: auto;`

Comment: Thanks! I just removed the menu class from the layout, only left it for the menu itself. it was an accident.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the container with the content div in your header div.

That should help you.